# Connecting to SQL Server from java with TCP disabled

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, shared-memory

I'm trying to connect to a local database (SQL Server 2008) from Java.
I have disabled the tcp connections per customer requirements and I can't connect.
I have to disable too the service SQL Server Browser.

I write the next statement in Java:

```
conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;user=user;password=password");
```

and I have the following error:

> "java.net.SocketTimeoutException:
>   Receive timed out". (then it tells me
>   that probably there is a firewall and
>   that I should run the SQL Server
>   Browser).

If I try to connect from the Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio and I can connect whith the same parameters:

```
Server type: Database Engine
Server name: localhost\SQLEXPRESS
Authentication: SQL Server Authentication
User: user
Password: password
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong i Java but SQL Server Managment Studio is actually a client, so if it can connect any client should can.

Please answer. If you need more information just ask for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to SQL Server LocalDB using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345746/connecting-to-sql-server-localdb-using-jdbc)

Comment: Did you get a solution to this issue? I am also having the same requirement.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, Microsoft's JDBC driver does not support named pipes connections to SQLServer. You can try finding and alternative JDBC driver to use.

Take a look at [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html). It's free, open source, and it connects to SQLServer using named pipes.

Comment: Hi.
Thanks for answering.
I'll try with jTDS, but  I have named piper disabled too, I want to use Shared Memory. I'm shure it can be done because my client can connect from .net to the same database with the same configuration. I'll try jTDS but I think is very sad that the Microsoft driver hasn't all the features.

Comment: Here is jtds example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345746/connecting-to-sql-server-localdb-using-jdbc/24412037#24412037

Comment: Did you get to succeed in connecting with the Shared Memory? I have also TCP/IP and named pipes disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the SQL Server Express version came with Visual Studio 2010. For other version there should be similar solutions but I have not tested. Here is the solution:

1. **Enable TCP/IP protocol.** Find "SQL Server Configuration Manager" from start menu, expand "SQL Server Network Configuration" and click on "Protocols for SQLEXPRESS", double click "TCP/IP" and change the "Enabled" property to "Yes". Check the "IP Addresses" tab and enable the IP addresses you wan to use (typically "127.0.0.1").
2. **Enable user sa in SQL Server.** Press Win+R, type in "sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS" and run the following commands:

   ```
   ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE;
   GO
   ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD='StrongPassword1!'
   GO
   ```
3. **Change the login mode to enable explicit login.** Press Win+R again and type in "regedit", find the following key

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer
   ```

   and then change the value "LoginMode" to 2.
4. **Test the configuration.** Create a test connection in Visual Studio 2010, uses user name "sa" and password "StrongPassword1!". if you can connect you should be able to connect through JDBC as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question. However, I was searching how to configure Shared Memory access to SQL Server using the Microsoft JDBC driver and came across it.
The definite answer is: The Microsoft JDBC driver only supports TCP connections, not shared memory nor named pipes. Now that the driver is open source, you can check that yourself in the source code on GitHub: The relevant code is the local class `TDSChannel` in toplevel class `IOBuffer` (currently found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/519186396ec8c9c00add45b98d75f1a61d0ceabd/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/IOBuffer.java#L557)). Method `open` in this class only accesses tcp sockets (and SSL sockets), but not any shared memory or named pipes.

This means that using other drivers than the MS JDBC driver is the only possibility when you cannot or do not want to use TCP/IP connections.