# Can the JDBC driver be configured to use a Shared Memory protocol

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I work in a very restrictive environment and I am trying to configure a Java application to connect to my local running instance of SQL Server.

The Share Memory, TCP/IP and Named Pipe client protocols are enabled but only the Shared Memory protocol is enabled as part of the "Network Configuration" for my SQL Server instance. So whenever I try to establish a connection I get the error,

"Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port."

I'm pretty sure it's because TCP/IP isn't enabled on the instance. So is there a way to specify in the JDBC URL that shared memory should be used or is this not possible?

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4806320/3916). If you want named pipe support, use jTDS. If you are stuck with the Microsoft Type 4 JDBC driver, then you must enable TCP/IP connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to it, have you considered ODBC?

You can setup an ODBC DS to use a Named Pipe and then connect to it through a JDBC URL so:

```
"jdbc:odbc:DSName"
```

Does that help?