# Connect to SQL Server localdb JDBC

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, localdb

I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express **localdb** on my system.

After I created (and started) a Instance (Test) with an database (db1) I tried to connect with my java-Applikation.

The driver ist "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver".

My connection-string is "jdbc:sqlserver://(localdb)\Test;databaseName=db1;schema=db1;"

Error (truncated):
java.net.UnknownHostException: '(localdb)' named instance 'Test' 
Check UDP Port 1434
Check if SQL Server browser-Service is started

My .NET Framework Version is 4.0.2

'SQLCMD.EXE -S(localdb)\Test' works fine.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. See [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15176091/376366).

Answer (score 6):

The Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver does not support localDB. See the comment http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx#10250447

> Krzysztof Kozielczyk - MSFT 22 Dec 2011 11:10 AM
>   #
>
> @Charles Stanton
>
> Unfortunately JDBC driver doesn't support LocalDB at this moment and
>   there is no easy workaround. The team is aware of this missing
>   feature, but filing a connect item is always helpful for DCR tracking
>   and prioritization.
>
> Thanks,
>
> -Krzysztof

As explained by an answer in [Connecting to SQL Server LocalDB using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345746/connecting-to-sql-server-localdb-using-jdbc), it is possible to do this using the jTDS driver.