# connect MSVS local db using jdbc to jaspesoft software in same pc?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, localdb

I have a local db, which has a connection string

```
Data Source=(localdb)\projectsv12;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

This database has no username and password.

I am using this database in Visual Studio SQL manager.

I have external software in which I need to access this database using a JDBC connection. So it's asking for a JDBC URL.

```
  jdbc url format:  jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=database
```

What should I provide to connect to my database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to SQL Server LocalDB using JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345746/connecting-to-sql-server-localdb-using-jdbc)

Comment: AFAIK nothing has changed since above question: it is not possible with the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver, it might be possible with the jTDS driver.