# MSSQL - Connection String

Tags: java, c#, sql-server, spring, entity-framework

I have made a project using Entity Framework in Visual Studio. I have following connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="HospitalManagementEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/HospitalEntities.csdl|res://*/HospitalEntities.ssdl|res://*/HospitalEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=HospitalManagement;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="HospitalManagementContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/HospitalManagement.csdl|res://*/HospitalManagement.ssdl|res://*/HospitalManagement.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=HospitalManagement;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

It connects with the mssql.

But when I try to connect with same database from Java - Hibernate/Spring it gives me error.

**UDP** Connection String

```
<bean id="dataSourceMain"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=HospitalManagement;integratedSecurity=true;Trusted_Connection=yes;" />
  </bean>
```

**Error**

> Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The connection to the
>   host localhost, named instance sqlexpress failed. Error:
>   "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the
>   server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP
>   traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the
>   SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.

**TCP** Connection String

```
<bean id="dataSourceMain"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=HospitalManagement;integratedSecurity=true;Trusted_Connection=yes;" />
  </bean>
```

**Error**

> Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The TCP/IP connection
>   to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection
>   refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an
>   instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port
>   are not blocked by a firewall.".

**Ports Info**

[image]

**Netstat**

[image]

*Questions*

As you can see that both udp and tcp ports are blocked/inactive.

1) So how Visual Studio managed to get connected to MSSQL ?

2) What protocol does Entity framework uses in above case ?

3) Is there a way to connect to Mssql in Java - Hibernate/Spring, bypassing the firewall or udp/tcp requirements ?

*P.S. I have no admin rights.* So for now I can't enable TCP/IP port.

Comment: Is your java project on another pc?

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev its on same pc.

Comment: Did you try with default port number `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433`?

Comment: Yes. Its TCP/IP port. It still gives error, same as above(tcp).

Comment: Without enabling TCP/IP jdbc can not connect to ms sql. EF connects with named pipes, and you may need alternative jdbc like [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html)  and  [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15176091/2794280)

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev as you see above that named pipes are disabled too. Is there any other work around ?