# How to connect to localdb in Rider?

Tags: sql-server, localdb, rider

Trying to connect to localdb using Database tab in Rider.
I adding SqlServer jTds and Rider shows this error

> Connection to SunEngineDb1 failed. [08S01] Network error IOException:
>   .\pipe\MSSQL$LOCALDB#E65C6709\sql\query (Can not find the specified
>   file)

[image]

What am I missing, and how it can be solved?

It is ASP.NET Core 2.0 project with localdb database on development. If I run it it works perfectly including database connect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345746/connecting-to-sql-server-localdb-using-jdbc

Comment: Hello! Did you connect according to the tutorial? https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2016/10/07/connecting-datagrip-to-sql-server-express-localdb/

Comment: @moscas Hallow! Yes, tried this, and tried also to extract pipename from `SqlLocalDB.exe info`. But not 100% equal, i use Windows Domain Autentification.

Comment: Did you download drivers by presing 'Download' in Rider?

Comment: @moscas Yes. Installed version 1.3.1 latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, finally we discovered the problem. It is the mistake in the driver we provide. To have this issue fixed urgently, delete the file \config\jdbc-drivers\jdbc-drivers.xml and restart the IDE. Then, please, refresh your driver to `1.3.1.1` or just put `[latest]` there.