# Can Flyway use a Sql Express LocalDB

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, integration-testing, flyway, localdb

We've got an application based on microservices. The deployed application will be running on a full version of Microsoft SQL Server. For UnitTesting i wanted to use a clean localdb instance of SQL-Express, to ensure a constant output of my tests.
For managing the database schemes we are using flyway scripts.

**Now the big question:**
Is it possible to use flyway on a localdb instance?

(I didn't find anything on it around the internet.)

Any help is welcome!

Edit: Solution found! See post below

Edits:
Here is what I get, by trying to connect to my localdb instance

```
ERROR:
Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:sqlserver://(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;databaseName=IntegrationTest;integratedSecurity=true) for user 'sa': Fehler beim Herstellen einer Verbindung mit dem Host "(localdb)", benannte Instanz "mssqllocaldb". Fehler: "java.net.UnknownHostException: (localdb)". Überprüfen Sie die Server- und Instanznamen, und stellen Sie sicher, dass der UDP-Datenverkehr an Port 1434 nicht von einer Firewall blockiert wird. Überprüfen Sie für SQL Server 2005 oder höher, ob der SQL Server-Browserdienst auf dem Host ausgeführt wird.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08S01
Error Code : 0
Message    : Fehler beim Herstellen einer Verbindung mit dem Host "(localdb)", benannte Instanz "mssqllocaldb". Fehler: "java.net.UnknownHostException: (localdb)". Überprüfen Sie die Server- und Instanznamen, und stellen Sie sicher, dass der UDP-Datenverkehr an Port 1434 nicht von einer Firewall blockiert wird. Überprüfen Sie für SQL Server 2005 oder höher, ob der SQL Server-Browserdienst auf dem Host ausgeführt wird.

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Fehler beim Herstellen einer Verbindung mit dem Host "(localdb)", benannte Instanz "mssqllocaldb". Fehler: "java.net.UnknownHostException: (localdb)". Überprüfen Sie die Server- und Instanznamen, und stellen Sie sicher, dass der UDP-Datenverkehr an Port 1434 nicht von einer Firewall blockiert wird. Überprüfen Sie für SQL Server 2005 oder höher, ob der SQL Server-Browserdienst auf dem Host ausgeführt wird.
```

I tested the suggestion of Jeroen Mosterd in the comments. It seems I might have come a step further, but there still seems to be something missing. The linked Question as well as the SqlLocalDB.exe tell me something about \tsql\query but flyway will only use \sql\query

```
ERROR:
Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://./IntegrationTest;instance=LOCALDB#5F8273EF;namedPipe=true) for user 'ddlAdmin': Network error IOException: \\.\pipe\MSSQL$LOCALDB#5F8273EF\sql\query (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08S01
Error Code : 0
Message    : Network error IOException: \\.\pipe\MSSQL$LOCALDB#5F8273EF\sql\query (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: \\.\pipe\MSSQL$LOCALDB#5F8273EF\sql\query (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\.\pipe\MSSQL$LOCALDB#5F8273EF\sql\query (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting to SQL Server LocalDB using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345746/connecting-to-sql-server-localdb-using-jdbc)

Comment: The `MSSQL$` issue is also discussed in the linked query, with a link to [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/716/). Overall, though, these issues would make me wary of using LocalDB in combination with JDBC at all; just taking the path of least resistance and installing SQL Server Express seems better, otherwise the configuration drifts farther away from production the more hacks and forks you need to apply. Not sure why this wouldn't get you a "constant output" or why that would be important, but you could always programmatically restart the server.

Comment: I would love to simply use SQL Server Express, but sadly thats a little hard to achieve in our company ^^ Our IT department is rather restrictive in giving us decelopers enough rights. I'm already happy to be able to work using a localdb on my computer. We've got a development Database on our SQL Server but I prefer using some local Server to make sure I've got a clean Database for my Tests.<br>
Thank you anyways for pointing me in the right direction. I stumbled over that question before but you made me re-read it and made me find a viable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to replace the jTDS driver of Flyway with the newer [Alternative jTDS Driver](https://github.com/milesibastos/jTDS/releases) from a Fork of the original jTDS. The Link of [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) did help me in pointing me in the right direction of using the new connection String and finding the new driver.

How to work around:
copy `jtds-1.3.3.jar` to your drivers folder in your FlywayVersion
remove the deprecated `jtds-1.3.1.jar`
execute `SqlLocalDB.exe info MSSQLLocalDB` to get your Pipename
`Pipename der Instanz: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#5F8273EF\tsql\query`
use only the `LOCALDB#5F8273EF` part in your connectionstring in flyway
Connectionstring:
`flyway.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://./<DatabaseName>;instance=LOCALDB#5F8273EF;namedPipe=true`

Important: Make sure to create the database and the user you want to use in flyway before executing the script.