# PySpark connectivity to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pyspark

I am trying to establish a connection to a LocalDB instance in SQL Server 2019 (server name: `ProjectLocalDB`).

When using PYODBC, I am able to connect:

```
import pyodbc

server = "(LocalDB)\\ProjectLocalDB"
database = "my_db"
trusted_connection = "yes"

conn = pyodbc.connect(
    f"Driver={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};"
    f"Server={server};"
    f"Database={database};"
    f"Trusted_Connection={trusted_connection};"
)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT @@version")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print(row[0])
    row = cursor.fetchone()

conn.close()
```

This is my Pyspark code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

server_name = "(LocalDB)\\ProjectLocalDB"
dbname = "my_db"
table_name = "dbo.polls_choice"

jdbc_driver_path = "E:\Program Files\SSMS\sqljdbc_12.6\enu\jars\mssql-jdbc-12.6.1.jre8.jar"

jdbc_url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{server_name};databaseName={dbname};integratedSecurity=true;loginTimeout=60;"

employees_df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbc_url) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .load()
```

When I run the PySpark, I am getting following error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o72.load.
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host ProjectLocalDB, port 1433 has failed.
> Error: "ProjectLocalDB. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

I have tried to debug, making sure TCP/IP is enabled, and I even switched off the firewall (although config was done to allow SQL Server to run). I would really appreciate any suggestions on how this issue can be fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think jdbc supports localDb cause it uses named pipes while jdbc works only with tcpip. Why do you need to use toy servers, SQL Server Express is much better

Comment: Would this work on a local machine? If I try to use '.' as the server, I am getting same error

Comment: You can try anything, but the microsoft jdbc driver doesn't work with localdb. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345746/connecting-to-sql-server-localdb-using-jdbc

Comment: Well, checked following page: [link](https://kontext.tech/article/290/connect-to-sql-server-in-spark-pyspark)  - seems that local machine (.) should be working, just for some reason I keep getting the Port Error.

Comment: You'll have to use an old fork of jtds driver for that, did you do that

Comment: server_name = "."
dbname = "Project_ADDS"
table_name = "dbo.population_data"

jdbc_driver_path = "E:\Program Files\SSMS\sqljdbc_12.6\enu\jars\mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar"

jdbc_url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{server_name};databaseName={dbname};integratedSecurity=true;loginTimeout=10;"

employees_df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbc_url) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .load()

employees_df.show()

spark.stop()     -> still getting same error with this code

Comment: Where in your code did you use *jtds* driver? :)