# How to visualize SQL Server database made from ASP.NET Core Web API with DBVisualizer

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-webapi, dbvisualizer

I'm a beginner in ASP.NET Core, SQL and DBVisualizer (in web programming in general).

I would like to visualize my database with DBVisualizer but I get an error :

> An error occurred while establishing the connection:
>
> Long Message:
> Failed to connect TCP/IP to host localhost, port 5041. Error: “The driver received an unexpected preconnect response.
> Review the connection properties and verify that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections to the port. This driver can only be used with SQL Server 2005 or later.
> ClientConnectionId:41197c49-49ad-4191-8bdc-0dd7905eaede

FYI I translated everything after `Long Message:` from French to English.

In `Program.cs`, I create the DB context like that :

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

My connection string in `appsettings.json` is :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=RestoCommandDB;Integrated Security=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
  },
```

Then on DBVisualizer side, I configure my connection like that :

[image: DB Visualizer config]

I have no userId or password that I know of. The ping works.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you're using LocalDb, you might need to use jtds driver: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345746/connecting-to-sql-server-localdb-using-jdbc