# Not able to connect sql server 2008 r2 with java

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, tcp

I am trying to connect sql server 2008 r2 with my java code , But it is showing me this error .

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host DINESH-PC, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:171)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1033)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

my code is:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=sa;password=123456";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
    if (conn != null) {
        System.out.println("Connected");
    }
```

i am using jre7 and sqljdbc4-3.0.jar is included in library.

Help me with ur suggesstions.

Comment: see what happens if you turn off the firewall on `DINESH-PC`

Comment: You have quite a lot of information from exception message. Just follow the hints. Check if all connection string are right. Check if DB server run. Check if there is no firewall blocking that port on server where DB is situated.

Comment: Check if this can help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806320/connecting-to-sql-server-from-java-with-tcp-disabled

Comment: i tried all ur suggestions ..... i am getting the same error

Comment: Are you sure that named instance (named "SQL2008") is running on standard port 1433 (which is used for default/unnamed SQL instance) (possible mistake here)? Check what port is used by your named instance - if it's dynamic port, check if Server Browser is up and running (and do not give exact port at connection string). Be sure that instance port and Server Browser port are open on firewall (Server Browser has static port and tells SQL clients which ports named instance are using).

Comment: guys finally came with a solution ......... sql server was not running in port 1433 , as @Milkmaid said its because of firewall....Then i turned firewall off , so that sql server can runs in the port 1433 ........ now my code is running perfectly.....thanks for all your help.............and also there were some changes in code.....which is updated in my question.....:)

Comment: @dheena you can mark my answer as right so it will be helpfull for others

Comment: ya @Milkmaid , I also mentioned it in my previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite a lot of information from exception message. Just follow the hints. Check if all connection string are right. Check if DB server run. Check if there is no firewall blocking that port on server where DB is situated.

also must check wheather tcp/ip is enabled ..

to check

- open sql server configration manager
- select sql server network configration
- then, select protocol for MSSQLSERVER
- them check wheather tcp/ip is enabled or not. If not enable it.